# Can't run ipython after installing using pip

Tags: python, pip, ipython

Trying to run ipython after installing via pip causes:

```
$ ipython
    -bash: ipython: command not found
```

Do I need to add a directory to my path? The python installation guide doesn't mention it:

http://ipython.org/install.html

Everything seems to be installed as expected:

```
$ pip show ipython
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: ipython
Version: 4.0.0
Summary: IPython: Productive Interactive Computing
Home-page: http://ipython.org
Author: The IPython Development Team
Author-email: ipython-dev@scipy.org
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: traitlets, pickleshare, simplegeneric, decorator, gnureadline, appnope, pexpect
```

I'm currently using python version 2.7.10 on Mac OS X 10.11

**EDIT:**

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing and now I'm getting this error:

```
sudo -H pip install ipython
Collecting ipython
  Downloading ipython-4.0.0-py2-none-any.whl (730kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 733kB 459kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pickleshare in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gnureadline in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): appnope in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pexpect in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): path.py in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pickleshare->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ptyprocess>=0.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pexpect->ipython)
Installing collected packages: ipython
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 371, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 71, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share'
```

I guess this error may have happened the first time around, as it still thinks it has been installed properly!

Comment: Did you face any error while installing IPython ?

Comment: No I did not get any errors. Seems to be installed according to the pip show command

Comment: http://johnlaudun.org/20130902-ipython-command-not-found/ can u try this ?

Comment: I researched that page earlier, but I do not have the port command either.

Comment: This has been extremely painful for me. Please post if you've found a solution. I've been trying to use pip install --target, but it's a very very confusing alley to go down.

Comment: I'm afraid I never solved the problem, I ended up using an Ubuntu image provided by another student for the Audio DSP programming course I was doing. It saved a lot of time and headaches installing other tools as well. Still would be interested to know why it doesn't install on my system!

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem. When you uninstall and reinstall ipython, the error happens because of permission. You can delete the directory and reinstall by "sudo pip install ipython".
I don't know why but it installs in 'usr/local/bin' instead of 'usr/bin'. I have to use "sudo ipython" to run it.